# How to access external api using sails.js?

Tags: facebook, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to access information from facebook within a controller using sails.js. Here is my code:

```
module.exports = {


  commonLikes : function(req,res){
    var other_uid = req.param('uid');
    //var me = req.params.user.uid;
    console.log(other_uid);

    User.findOne({uid : other_uid}).done( function(err,data){
        var other = data;

    var http = require('http'), options = {
            host : "https://graph.facebook.com",
            port : 80,
            path : "/"+other.uid+"/likes?access_token="+other.token,
            method : 'GET'
    };

    var webservice_data = "";

    var webservice_request = http.request(options, function(webservice_response)
    {
        webservice_response.on('error', function(e){ console.log(e.message); });
        webservice_response.on('data', function(chunk){ webservice_data += chunk;});
        webservice_response.on('end', function(){res.send(webservice_data);});
        console.log('coucou');
    });



    });
  }

};
```

The http.request function doesn't look to work though and I get an error when trying to access /Likes/commonLikes?uid=XXXXX.

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Does anyone knows how I can access an external API using sails?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `host` shouldn't include the protocol:

```
    var http = require('http'), options = {
        host : "graph.facebook.com",
        port : 80,
        path : "/"+other.uid+"/likes?access_token="+other.token,
        method : 'GET'
    };
```

If you want to use `https`, use the `https` module instead of `http`, and use port 443. And don't forget to add `req.end()` when you're done with the request.